# How to disecretize and solve the 1D advection equation in MatLab

Tags: matlab, variables, velocity

I am currently working on a project involving two-phase flow through pipes and I am required to model it in MatLab. Even though I have started and get some pertinent results I get the feeling that something is not right and I think it might be the way I was solving the advection equations.

The equation I am trying to solve is

`d(Hl x rhoL)/dt + d(Hl x rhoL x Vl)/dx = 0`     ...... where: Hl=liquid fraction;
                                                       rhoL= liquid density;
                                                       Vl=liquid velocity;

The liquid being incompressible I do not take in account the density as it is constant.

I am trying to solve this equation for the liquid velocity at time t+dt (velocity is not constant).

What I have done so far is consider Hl=U and Hl x Vl= V and using a forward difference in time and backward difference in space I ended up with the following formula:

```
Vl(i,1)=(((Hlold(i,1)-Hl(i,1))*(deltaX/deltaT))+(Vl(i-1,1)*Hl(i-1,1)))/Hl(i,1));
```

Do you guys think this is correct? Can someone help me understand how I can disecretize the PDE having variale velocities through the nodes?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 2 general notes: 1) You might want to ask questions such as this on [engineering.se]. 2) When posting equations, it's often a better idea to write them in some math software (LaTeX, Mathtype etc.) and upload an image, or just link to an equation image on the web (that is, unless you're posting on some SE site that has support of LaTeX).